# Flutter Form Builder Radio Group has no option labels

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-form-builder

In a flutter app I using flutter_form_builder to implement a FormBuilderRadioGroup in a update form.

I have an integer field for user role and a boolean field user active which I want to set in a form. In both the radio group and drop down widgets there is only one option for a value instead of the expected label / value pair.

Is there any easy way to handle this rather than code around it?

Here is my code, the values are stored in my database as integers, not strings

```
FormBuilderRadioGroup(
  name: "role",
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: "Role",
     labelStyle: TextStyle(color: personLabelColor, fontSize: _user.fontsize, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)
  ),
  options: const [
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role1"),
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role2"),
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role3"),
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role4"),
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role5"),
    FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Role6"),
 ],
 initialValue: _person.role,
                          ),
```

Comment: I dont understand whats your problem exactly. You can set a `Text` as a child of `FormBuilderFieldOption` with your label and control it, right?

Comment: I want the label for the role to be the role name and the value to be an integer. For the active field I want the label to read yes and the value to be true just like in HTML.